# Thermostatic cartridge stuck

Tags: shower, valve, mixing-valve

I have a brand new thermostatic concealed cartridge in my shower. THERMOSTATIC CARTRIDGE FOR CVD CONCEALED SHOWER VALVE PRE-JANUARY 2015. When trying to remove it to recalibrate it, the outer brass housing unscrewed from the outer brass fitting. Now the outer housing that screws into the brass mixer is stuck. I need to get it out without damaging the mixer body. Any suggestions? The issue is the the valve it comprised of two main brass parts. One that screws into the brass diverter housing and the other one that screws into the first one that screws into the housing. The two have become separated and the first one is now stuck in the housing. [image]

Comment: The description is unclear - it did unscrew and then it didn't unscrew, or part of it unscrewed and another part didn't? Anyway, [edit] to add pictures showing the issue. If it's galled or cross-threaded badly enough the "without damaging the mixer body" ship may already have sailed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Photos and a precise make and model would be helpful.   You can add photos by clicking "Edit" above, and using the editor functions.

Comment: It looks like left turn not right turn